# How to detect if button is disabled in source

Tags: vba, web-crawler

I want to scrape a website. It has dropdown menus. When nothing is selected in the dropdown menus, the search button is greyed-out/non-clickable. The source code of the button is like this:

```
<br>
<span class="search search-disabled" id="by_item">Search</span>
<span class="reset search-disabled" id="reset_item">Reset</span>
<div class="clear">
::before
::after
</div>
<br>
```

When the dropdown menus are populated, the button is enabled and the source code is like this:

```
<br>
<span class="search" id="by_item">Search</span>
<span class="reset" id="reset_item">Reset</span>
<div class="clear">
::before
::after
</div>
<br>
```

For example, for the search button: I would like to check if the button is disabled or enabled, so that I can move on with my code. I need to find it by class name, id is not working for my code. But when I try to find "search search-disabled", sometimes I get an error.

How can I check if the button is enabled or disabled?

Comment: Is it by IE object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first word before space is the class name you should go for (`search` and `reset`). You can extract the current class name by `className property and check if it has the keyword you are looking for. Supposing that you are using IE object and it is the first element in the source code, a sample code should look like this:

```
Set btn = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("search")(0)
If InStr(1, btn.className, "search-disabled", vbTextCompare) Then
    'your code when button is disabled
Else
    'your code when button is enabled
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: @Tehscript, just to clarify for readers, the _search_ and  _search-disabled_ are both class names, and each could be found by the `getElementsByClassName` method. the code snippet looks for the class name that is always there (_search_) and checks if the second class name is assigned to the node that is found

Comment: @jsotola indeed, thank you for clarification. I am not good at technically explaining things.

Comment: @Tehscript, me too. i had to double check on the web before i  posted the comment